# Forward network traffic on iPhone through sshuttle tunnel on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh-tunnel, ios, socks, sshuttle

Is it possible to forward my network traffic on my iPhone through a [`sshuttle`](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) tunnel on my Mac (on the same WiFi network)?